# GCP - Can't create a tpu on europe-west1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp, google-compute-engine

I'my trying to create a tpu for my vm instance [from this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/transformer-pytorch) but get this error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.tpus.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Location europe-west1-b is not found or access is unauthorized.
```

I have enabled all of the access the vm can have but i still have this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ["TPU types and zones"](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/types-zones) TPUs are only available in a very limited set of regions, namely:

- **Europe, Middle East and Africa**

  - europe-west4-a (Eemshaven, Netherlands)
- **Americas**

  - us-central1-a, b, c and f (Council Bluffs, Iowa, USA)
- **Asia-Pacific**

  - asia-east1-c (Changhua County, Taiwan)

*Note: not every SKU is available in each region, so double check the above page when planning your deployments.*

In addition to specifying a valid zone, you will need to make sure the [TPU API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/tpu.googleapis.com) is enabled, and your account has the relevant IAM permissions: Cloud TPU\TPU Admin.

At the moment TPUs are predominantly designed for centralised data processing rather than close-to-edge processing. Hence the somewhat limited number of locations TPUs are available within.